# JQuery trying to print columns of a table where a checkbox is ticked, then printing a response from a web server

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, forms, html-table

I am trying to create a URL using JQuery and am having a small issue. I am printing a table to my page like so  :

```
   <table id="employeeTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Branch</th>
                <th>Phone No.</th>
                <th>Extension</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var prod in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@prod.FullName</td>
                    <td>@prod.Branch</td>
                    <td>@prod.PhoneNo</td>
                    <td>@prod.Extension</td>
                    <td>@prod.Email</td>
                    @if (User.IsInRole(@"Admins") || User.Identity.Name == prod.DomainAC)
                    {
                        <td><a href="/home/edit/@prod.Id"  style="color: blue;">edit</a></td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>User => @User.ToString()</td>   
                    }
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="message" value="@prod.PhoneNo">Message<br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I then have a form below this where I am asking the user to input some values :

```
@{if (IsPost) {
      string ua = Request["u"];
      string pa = Request["p"];
      string ma = Request["m"]; 
    <p>You entered: </p>
    <p>Company Name: @ua </p>
    <p>Contact Name: @pa </p>
    <p>Contact Name: @ma </p>
    <p>It should appear here, but it won't =></p>
    <p id="out"></p>
  }
  else
  {
    <form method="post" runat="server" id="FormID">
        Username:<br />
        <input type="text" name="u" id="u" /><br />
        Password<br />
        <input type="text" name="p" id="p" /><br />
        <br />
        Password<br />
        <textarea name="m" id="m" cols="25" rows="5">
        Enter your comments here...
        </textarea><br>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" id="thebutton" />
    </form>
}
```

I want to use my JQuery to construct a URL, navigate to it and print the response on screen - using values from the checkboxes in the table and from my form, so in my script I have :

```
<script>
    $("#thebutton").click(function () {
        $('#out').text('');
        var form = $(document.getElementById('FormID'));
        var urlToConstruct = 'http://webaddress.com/web/d.php';
        urlToConstruct += '?u=' + form.find('#u').val();
        urlToConstruct += '&p=' + form.find('#p').val();
        $('#employeeTable tr').has(':checkbox:checked').find('td:eq(2)').each(function () {
            urlToConstruct += ($(this).text());
        });
        alert(urlToConstruct);
    });
</script>
```

The URL I want to construct from this form is :

```
http://webaddress.com/web/d.php?u=<Username entered by user>&p=<Password entered by user>&s=<List of Phone Numbers from the C# above where the checkbox is selected, comma separated>&m=<Comment submitted by user>
```

So, if my name is "John", Password is "Password1", Comment is "Test" and I have selected one checkbox for a user with the phone number "12345678", the URL I will navigate to is :

```
http://webaddress.com/web/d.php?u=John&p=Password1&s=12345678&m=Test
```

Ideally I would like to print the response of the webpage in a  while still on the same parent web page rather than going to a new one if this is possible.

So, my questions -

- How can I fix my JQuery above so it will `alert()` with the correct
  URL constructed ?
- How can I display the response from the server when    I click
  submit, within a div, without navigating away from the parent
  site?

UPDATE :

This is driving me crazy :). I've tried removing the alert and simply viewing the url created in fiddler. The form parts of the JQuery work; the table part simply refuses to.

UPDATE #2 :

Script :

```
<script>
    $("#thebutton").click(function () {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var $form = $('#FormID');
        var urlToConstruct = 'http://webaddress.com/web/d.php';
        urlToConstruct += '?u=' + $form.find('#u').val();
        urlToConstruct += '&p=' + $form.find('#p').val();

        var phoneNumbers =
            $.map($('#employeeTable').find('input:checked')
                    .parent()
                    .siblings('.js-phoneNumbers'),
                  function (elem, index) {
                      return $(elem).text();
                  });

        urlToConstruct += 's=' + phoneNumbers.join(',');

        alert(urlToConstruct);
        form.submit();
    });
</script>
```

HTML :

```
    <table id="employeeTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Branch</th>
                <th>Phone No.</th>
                <th>Extension</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var prod in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@prod.FullName</td>
                    <td>@prod.Branch</td>
                    <td class="js-phoneNumbers">@prod.PhoneNo</td>
                    <td>@prod.Extension</td>
                    <td>@prod.Email</td>
                    @if (User.IsInRole(@"Admins") || User.Identity.Name == prod.DomainAC)
                    {
                        <td><a href="/home/edit/@prod.Id"  style="color: blue;">edit</a></td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>User => @User.ToString()</td>   
                    }
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="message" value="@prod.PhoneNo">Message<br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Still no alert dialog :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var form = $(document.getElementById('FormID'));`

1. I don't see an element with the id `FormID` in your markup.
2. Why the `document.getElementById('FormID')`? Since you have already included jQuery, simply use `var form = $('#FormID');`

If you could update your question with the proper markup, I could help you further.

Another thought, your click handler is attached to the `submit` button of the form. Meaning, the default action performed by the browser on clicking that button is to submit the form. If you still wish to explicitly submit the form, you may want to modify your click handler as follows:

```
$("#thebutton").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // rest of the code as before
    ...
    ...
});
```

3rd thought, you could restructure you markup and js as follows,

```
<table id="employeeTable">
    <thead>
        // markup as before
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var prod in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                // markup as before
                <td class="js-phoneNumbers">@prod.PhoneNo</td>
                // markup as before
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>


$("#thebutton").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var $form = $('#FormID');
    var urlToConstruct = 'http://webaddress.com/web/d.php';
    urlToConstruct += '?u=' + $form.find('#u').val();
    urlToConstruct += '&p=' + $form.find('#p').val();

    var phoneNumbers = 
        $.map($('#employeeTable').find('input:checked')
                .parent()
                .siblings('.js-phoneNumbers'),
              function (elem, index){
                  return $(elem).text();
              });

    urlToConstruct += 's=' + phoneNumbers.join(',');

    alert(urlToConstruct);
    form.submit();
});
```

The `td` that we are interested in, I have given it a specific class `js-phoneNumbers`. The `js` prefix conveys to the reader that the class is chiefly to be used via js and not meant for styling.

The click handler then uses this class instead of a magic `td:eq(2)`. I feel the intent is conveyed more clearly this way.

The `$.map` is used to transform an array of jquery elements to an array of strings (ie, phone numbers).

The code you previously had to construct the phonenumber part of the url was wrong. Cheifly `&s=` was not added to the url and the phone numbers were not comma separated.

Comment: I have fixed the markup now I believe, apologies for any errors that were there. I have also fixed the error with forgetting the form id, thank you very much for pointing these out. Unfortunately the problem still persists - there is no alert posted when I press submit :(. Any more guidance you could give me in this question would be greatly appreciated as I am completely stuck! :) Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer with 2 more threads of thought. I believe the 3rd one should answer your question.

Comment: I really like how you did this and answered this. A great solution with an explanation so I can learn from it! Brilliant! Thank you very much, I am trying to implement this now and will write a reply with how I get on later. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I just gave this a shot and updated my question with what I am running - unfortunately I am still not getting an alert dialog! :( Firebug and IE Developer Tools throw no bug, but also give no indication of what the problem may be !